# How to access nested dictionary keys that change?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, nested

```
{
    "1": {
        "Furia": "0",
        "Chaos": "1"
    },
    "2": {
        "Furia": "0",
        "Chaos": "2"
    },
    "3": {
        "Furia": "0",
        "Chaos": "3"
    },
```

However let say in another match two different teams are playing with different names, how can I access that information. There will always be two teams though. I know how to access Furia and Chaos specifically only.

Comment: Lets call this dictionary as `d`. If you want the teams of a specific match number, you can use `d[*match number here*].keys()`. This will return list of team names that played the match.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to access? Names? Scores? Both?

Comment: @JackFleeting my output is 1. Chaos won the round 2. Chaos won the round but teams names will be changing so wanted to know how to store values in variables

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear. If the 1,2,3 keys refer to the round number, then round 2 was won by Chaos 2:0; how do you get to 1 from that?

Comment: @JackFleeting https://repl.it/repls/AnguishedWavyProfiles simpler if u just ran the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values of the keys in the dictionary you want to access by using `dict.keys()`
And store the values in variables, and use those variables to access the values you want.
For example:

```
dict1={ "item1":1,"item2":2}
>>> dict1.keys()
dict_keys(['item1', 'item2'])
>>> list_of_keys=[x for x in dict1.keys()]
>>> list_of_keys
['item1', 'item2']
>>> dict1[list_of_keys[1]]
2
```

Answer (score 0):

By looping its keys we can access them.

```
nest_dict = {
    "1": {
        "Furia": "0",
        "Chaos": "1"
    },
    "2": {
        "Furia": "0",
        "Chaos": "2"
    },
    "3": {
        "Furia": "0",
        "Chaos": "3"
    }
}

# Outer loop for getting the keys ['1', '2', '3'] 
for key in nest_dict:
   print(f"{key}:")

   # Inner loop for getting the keys ["Furia", "Chaos"]
   for team in nest_dict[key]:
       print(f"{team} scored: {nest_dict[key][team]}")

   # Printing new line for output readablility
   print()

# Alternate Way
print("Alternate Output\n")
for key in nest_dict:
   print(f"{key}:")

   # Since there will always be two teams.
   team1, team2 = nest_dict[key].keys()

   print(team1, team2)
   print(nest_dict[key][team1], nest_dict[key][team2])

   # Printing new line for output readablility
   print()
```

**Output:**

```
1:
Furia scored: 0
Chaos scored: 1

2:
Furia scored: 0
Chaos scored: 2

3:
Furia scored: 0
Chaos scored: 3

Alternate Output

1:
Furia Chaos
0 1

2:
Furia Chaos
0 2

3:
Furia Chaos
0 3
```